# Cant get social media feed to work in firebase and swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I've been trying to make this feed work for days now, and I'm simply stumped. I called a getData method to try and retrieve a list of post IDs from a user to then get their data and put it into a feed. However, when I run the code the feed comes up blank, however the data gets printed out to the console after the post ID's are pulled. So, it's not an issue with connectivity or anything, it's simply my code structure. The "scope" variable is the beginnings of a basic attempt at pagination of data, but really I'm just trying to get it to work at all at the moment. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here's my code:

```
//
//  ProfileFeedViewController.swift
//  Meditation
//
//  Created by Harper Chisari on 7/27/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Harper Chisari. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase

var currentPA: Array<String> = []

class ProfileFeedViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet var profileFeedTableView: UITableView!


var posts: [Post] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let scope = 0
    
    posts = createArray(scope: scope)
    profileFeedTableView.reloadData()
    
    }
    
    
}
func createPostArray(scope: Int, uid: String) -> Array<String>{
    db.collection("users")
    .document(uid)
        .getDocument { (document, error) in
            
            // Check for error
            if error == nil {
                
                // Check that this document exists
                if document != nil && document!.exists {
                    
                    let documentData = document!.data()
                    
                    let postArray = documentData?["post id's"] as! Array<String>
                    print(postArray)
                    //if postArray.count >= 25 { currentPA = Array( postArray[0+scope*25...24+scope*25])} else {
                        currentPA = postArray
                    print(currentPA)
                    //    }
                    
                } else {
                    print("huh?")
                }
            
                
            }else{
                print(error!)
                }}
    /*db.collection("users")
        .document(uid)
                .getDocument { (document, error) in
                
                // Check for error
                if error == nil {
                    
                    // Check that this document exists
                    if document != nil && document!.exists {
                        
                        let documentData = document!.data()
                        
                        let postArray = documentData?["post id's"] as! Array<String>
                        print(postArray)
                        //if postArray.count >= 25 { currentPA = Array( postArray[0+scope*25...24+scope*25])} else {
                            currentPA = postArray
                        print(currentPA)
                        //    }
                        
                    } else {
                        print("huh?")
                    }
                
                    
                }else{
                    print(error!)
                    }}*/
    print("ye")
    print(currentPA)
    return currentPA
}



func createArray(scope: Int) -> [Post] {
    var tempPosts: [Post] = []
    let currentPA = createPostArray(scope: scope, uid: uid)
    print("listen")
    print(currentPA)
    print("hey")
    for i in currentPA {
        print(i)
        db.collection("posts")
                    .document(i)
                    .getDocument { (document, error) in
                    
                    // Check for error
                    if error == nil {
                        
                        // Check that this document exists
                        if document != nil && document!.exists {
                            
                            let documentData = document!.data()
                            let postText = documentData?["post text"]
                            let postUser = documentData?["uid"]
                            Storage.storage().reference().child("posts").child("\(i)_post_image.png")
                                .getData(maxSize: 10*1024*1024, completion: {(data, error) -> Void in
                                if error != nil {
                                    print("oh no, the following error occured: \(String(describing: error))")
                                } else {
                                    let image : UIImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
                                    //uid
                                    
                                    db.collection("users")
                                        .document(postUser as! String)
                                             .getDocument { (document, error) in
                                             
                                             // Check for error
                                             if error == nil {
                                                 
                                                 // Check that this document exists
                                                 if document != nil && document!.exists {
                                                     
                                                     let documentData = document!.data()
                                                    let username = documentData?["username"]
                                                    let postImage = image
                                                    tempPosts.append(Post(image: postImage, username: username as! String, textcontent: postText as! String))
                                                }}}
                                    
                                    
                                    }})
                            
                            
                            
                        }} else {
                        print(error)
                        }}
    }
    //let post1 = Post(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BANNER.png"), username: "banncer", textcontent: "penis")
   // let post2 = Post(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BANNER.png"), username: "banncer", textcontent: "wenis")
    
   // tempPosts.append(post1)
    //tempPosts.append(post2)
    return tempPosts
}






extension ProfileFeedViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "posterCell") as! postCell
    
    cell.setPost(post: post)
    
    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: There are a number of issues with the code. However, there are two bottom line problems - 1) Firebase is asynchronous and you need to wait for data to be returned from the server before working with it - that happens within the closure following the firebase function `.getDocument`. This line `profileFeedTableView.reloadData()` will be called way before the vars are populated.  2) You cannot *return* data from a Firebase closure with this `return currentPA` You will need to implement a completion handler for that. Search SO for *[firebase][swift]firebase is async* and read the Q&A's.

Answer (score 1):

Your tableview is using `var posts: [Post] = []` as the datasource, but after fetching the results, you're never setting the results to the posts array, or reloading your tableview `profileFeedTableView.reloadData()`

And as always, double check to make sure that you have your tableView dataSource and delegate set.

You're calling reload tableView in viewDidLoad before the documents have downloaded.  You need to call reload only after all of the data has been downloaded and your models created.  So call it at the end of `createArray` .

Comment: So Ive updated the code, however it still doesn't display. Here's the console output: `ye
[]
listen
[]
hey
["uIFyeRBQLugRqcBdPytZ", "7KtOeS2VgzRue5E0DFpP", "gWezrDP5UoZfAV2NaioL", "FQj4vO0mIDRQ2DEz4zLH"]
["uIFyeRBQLugRqcBdPytZ", "7KtOeS2VgzRue5E0DFpP", "gWezrDP5UoZfAV2NaioL", "FQj4vO0mIDRQ2DEz4zLH"]` As you can see, the code which sets the new array only runs after the data is set. I tried to put a while loop in the code to wait for the variable to change before continuing, but it simply times out.

Comment: I've also updated my code in the original question if you'd like to see the changes I made.

Comment: `profileFeedTableView.reloadData()` needs to be called after your data is created.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update your reload/batch update your tableView after the data has been set. In your implementation you are calling reloadData in viewDidLoad which is not guaranteed that the function calling Firebase is done/finished executing.You should reload data only when you get a completion closer from Firebase. Also in your tableView datasource implementation you are using posts array which seems to be never set even after you fetch data from firebase. I have taken part of your code snippet and added a simple fix. Check the code below.

```swift
func createArray(scope: Int) -> [Post] {
    var tempPosts: [Post] = []
    let currentPA = createPostArray(scope: scope, uid: uid)
 for i in currentPA {
// -------
}

// At the end of your loop you should set the posts and reload your tableView
self.posts = tempPosts
DispatchQueue.main.async {
self.profileFeedTableView.reloadData()
}


} // end of createArray function
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried that but it said “unknown identifier self”

Comment: Isn't your function inside a viewController? seif there means a currentViewController. Try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Ok, I put the function in the view controller and the error went away, but the posts still don’t show.

Comment: Ok, so now it works, but only after I reopen the view after viewing it once.

Comment: Try adding this on viewDidLoad before calling your function to set data. 
```profileFeedTableView.datasource = self```

Comment: I have edited the answer to call ```self. profileFeedTableView.reloadData```

Comment: Now let's try verifying that posts are being set. 
scroll up to the posts var and modify it to: - 
```var posts: [Post] = [] {
didSet {
self. profileFeedTableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Comment: No luck with that. Maybe move the posts declaration?

Comment: If that doesn’t work then you need to double check your helper function for creating posts. There must be  thread issue. One suggestion is try to use DispatchGroup and execute on main queue after data is fetched.

Comment: Here is the link to the doc about DispatchGroup: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup

Also check this article on how to use it: - https://riptutorial.com/ios/example/23213/dispatch-group---waiting-for-other-threads-completed-

Comment: I have attached a link to sample implementation. I will have a look on your two functions later when I have enough time. Meanwhile try to learn about it and search for relevant topics, that’s the best way to learn. https://riptutorial.com/ios/example/23213/dispatch-group---waiting-for-other-threads-completed-